# Who built Elantris?

Tags: cosmere, elantris

As it says in Elantris, only an Elantrian can create an Aon that has an effect. The problem is that in order to become an Elantrian, Elantris needs to exist (as shown by the fact that people became half Elantrians when the city was an incomplete Aon). So who built Elantris as a functional Aon?

Comment: check out [the Coppermind article](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Elantris_(city)#Construction) which has a section on the city construction, or also the [elantris-city](https://wob.coppermind.net/adv_search/?tags=elantris+city) tag on Arcanum

Comment: also see [this WoB](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/246/#e5502) that indicates that the 'broken' city was harming it's residents

Answer (score 6):

Elantris did not need to be built for there to be "Elantrians" (i.e. people capable of using AonDor).

In Elantris, the city is not the *source* of the power.  It is merely a conduit that allows for much easier access to the power.  The entire city was built around making the power stronger, and building that power directly into the city in various ways.  It is tied to the location where Elantris was built, you likely need [Connection](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Connection) to the area; but the city itself isn't necessary.

Presumably, the original Elantrians were regular people taken by some weak form of the Shaod, perhaps even similar to what we see happen in Elantris before the main Aon is fixed.  First, they would have figured out that they could make the Aons; then over time, they would have discovered the effects that different Aons had.  It would have been a slow process of discovering the rules that govern AonDor, similar to how we study sciences.  At some point, their knowledge of AonDor would have been good enough to make something complicated like Elantris.

The following from the Elantris annotations ([chapter 55](https://brandonsanderson.com/annotation-elantris-chapter-55/)) also supports this (emphasis mine):

> Only Elantrians can draw Aons in the air, so someone taken by the Shaod must have developed the writing system. That is part of what makes writing a noble art in Arelon–drawing the Aons would have been associated with Elantrians. **Most likely, the early Elantrians (who probably didn’t even have Elantris back then) would have had to learn the Aons by trial and error, finding what each one did, and associating its meaning and sound with its effect. The language didn’t develop, but was instead ‘discovered.’**
>
> There are likely Aons that haven’t even been found yet.

So basically, the cannon answer is that Elantris *probably* didn't exist until after people had begun being taken by the Shaod.  The fact that Brandon chose to say "probably" is the only thing that would make me somewhat skeptical of this answer.  It makes a lot of sense to me though that Elantris is really more of a technological achievement of AonDor, like modern medicine uses biology to make our lives better, the Elantrians did the same when making their city and knowledge of AonDor.

Comment: https://wob.coppermind.net/events/246-alloy-of-law-17th-shard-qa/#e5502 suggests that even without Shaod some primitive form of AonDor is possible - that people built Elantris to start Shaod. This is reasonable because for. eg. Forgery doesn't need anything like this, but is much less spectacular.